# Xcode 7.0.1 PhoneGap project doesn't connect to internet after update

Tags: ajax, xcode, cordova, phonegap-build

I've been working on a phonegap project and was previously using Xcode 6.4 to open it up and view it in the simulator. I ended up upgraded to 7.0.1 so I could test it on my actual device. After I updated Xcode my Ajax calls in my app now always fail and return an error (in the simulator and installed version on iphone).

The ajax connects fine if I run it in a browser or use the PhoneGap app to test the code (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/phonegap-developer/id843536693?mt=8).

I'm loading the same code and was literally using it fine and then a minute after the update the ajax calls don't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I uninstalled Xcode 7 and reinstalled 6.4. I opened up the project again and the Ajax calls work. Any ideas?

Comment: Apple added a new security feature called ATS (App Transport Security), that blocks non https connections, you can just add `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key> <dict> <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key> <true/> </dict>`  in your info.plist (there is a plugin that does that), it's not recommended doing this because it's insecure, if you provide more details, I can help you configure the ATS in a more secure way

Comment: Thanks for the info. All my links are currently http. The data I'm getting doesn't need to be encrypted, so I thought it was kind of pointless to SSL encrypt the information.

So if I add that code to the info.plist it will let http calls thru? If I'm not sending sensitive information back and forth does it really matter if it's https or not?

Comment: Even if you use http, if you only connect with your own server, there are better ways of configuring the ATS, like allowing http connections only to your server but block other (in case somebody is able to hack your app to make it connect to his own server or something like that).

Comment: @Cake, *Cordova* and *Phonegap Build* recently did an unannounced upgrade of plugins. Start your build again from scratch. Plugins and documentation are now available here: http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 Thanks alot! You should take your comments and add it as a form of answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Cake, *Cordova* and *Phonegap Build* recently did an unannounced upgrade of plugins. Start your build again from scratch. Plugins and documentation are now available here: http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/